# div one above the other in flexbox

Tags: html, angularjs, css, flexbox, z-index

My idea is, when my Boolean variable is `true`, than a grey container with a opacity overlaps the orange and with a higher `z-index`.

I can't click on some buttons or else inside the orange container.

But I need the `flexbox` on the wrapper.

At the moment, my idea with the `z-index` failed, and it's flex in a row.

How can I fix this and put the grey above the orange (both `100% width` and high of the wrapper) and still using `flexbox`.

**Important:** When its overlapped, I can't click in the orange container, looking like it is disabled.

I've got following code:

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.isDisabled = true;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 100;
}
.overlapped {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 102;
}
.someContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
  z-index: 101;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" class="wrapper">
  <div ng-if="isDisabled" class="overlapped"></div>
  <div class="someContent">I have some random content...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the container overlaying the other:

- just use `position:relative` in the parent `.wrapper` and `position:absolute` in `overlapped`

To disable the orange container:

- use `pointer-events:none` linked to your Boolean variable. (might be optional)

```js
angular.module("myApp", []).controller("myController", function($scope) {
  $scope.isDisabled = true;
  $scope.isPointer = true;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.overlapped {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
  opacity: 0.5;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
}
.someContent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
.pointer-events {
  pointer-events: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController" class="wrapper">
  <div ng-if="isDisabled" class="overlapped"></div>
  <div ng-if="isPointer" class="someContent pointer-events">I have some random content...</div>
</div>
```